# Magento writes system.log with log disabled

Tags: error, xml, log, system.log

I disabled logging from the System > Advanced > Developer screen (I've checked that is disabled for all the websites/stores/storeviews) but Magento continues to write errors inside "/var/log/system.log" like:

```
[...] ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): [...] in /lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 383
```

Are there errors that ignore the admin backend setting?

Comment: Can you read from which module this log comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that there was an extension with invalid xml data in one of its files, specifically a tag starting with a number.

```
<123abc></123abc>
```

Answer (score 3):

In `app/Mage.php` method `log()`:

```
    if (!self::$_isDeveloperMode && !$logActive && !$forceLog) {
        return;
    }
```

A log will be written if the system is in developer mode, or the log is active, or the `$forceLog` parameter is true.

Since you say logging is disabled, and since the error handler does *not* force logging (as defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php::mageCoreErrorHandler()`), your store most likely has developer mode enabled. Check your `.htaccess` and `index.php` files for anything that might be triggering that.

Comment: Developer mode looks disabled, I added a check in site footer "echo Mage::getIsDeveloperMode() ? 'Y' : 'N';" and it returns N (if I enable the developer mode from index.php the check returns Y, so the check is working)

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is an Mage::log() call with param $forceLog = true:

```
    public static function log($message, $level = null, $file = '', $forceLog = false)
```